# ESP8266 Arduino Hostname (MDNS)

Tags: esp8266, mdns

I am having problems with the hostname of my ESP8266. I am using the MDNSResponder and I can successfully access my device with mydevice.local

However, my WiFi router (Netgear WGR614) list the device as ESP_FEA38A. When I use 'Angry IP Scanner' on my mac, there is no hostname listed. Both, the ip scanner and the WiFi router both recognize several raspberrys and other devices like airport express.

Does anybody know what other host naming mechanisms are being used and how I can get my ESP8266 device getting listed with hostname?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the Arduino environment in the WiFi library there is a method for setting the hostname:

```
WiFi.hostname(newHostName);
```

Once I set this to the desired name the ESP8266 showed correctly in DHCP, on the router and, when available, was pingable. From my experimenting this needs to be done before any of the other WiFi actions for it to work effectively.

You can also include the Espressif SDK functionality although looking at the Arduino ESP8266 GitHub project it appears to already be included.

The Espressif SDK sets the hostname with the following command:

```
wifi_station_set_hostname(myHostname);
```

Comment: Also WiFi.mode must be active (not WIFI_OFF).